# Fps calculation of a video from android device is not working properly

Tags: android, opencv, frame-rate

We are developing an android app where we can take video and we need to extract frame from that video.We used chaquopy to integrate python in android studio.In python file,cv2.VideoCapture() works properly,so hopefully there is no issue in finding and loading the video.But whenever we are trying to know the fps of the video,it returns us 0.Can anyone please help us to get a solution for this problem?

here is a snippet of our code:

```
import cv2
import os
def hello(something):
    vid=cv2.VideoCapture('/storage/emulated/0/Movies/CameraX-Video/20_abc_.mp4')
    cur=0

    success=True
    path='/storage/emulated/0/Download'
    fps = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    return fps
  
    while(True):
        success,frame=vid.read()
        if(success==False):
            break
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'frame%d.jpg'%cur), frame)
        
        
        cur+=1
```

Comment: use native android APIs. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for reading videos or their metadata.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it says [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/140), Chaquopy's current OpenCV builds do not support reading video files.